# Django charfield model with db query

Tags: python, mysql, django, request, models

I am trying to generate a select menu on `hello.html` with a list from a db query.

My `models.py`:

```
class hello(models.Model):
    q = """
    SELECT * FROM ZONAS
    WHERE cod_zona = 1
    """
    db.query(q)
    nome = db.query(q)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=nome)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and `my views.py`:

```
def contato(request):
   form = hello()
   return render_to_response(
       'hello.html',
        locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
    )

def hello_template(request):
    form = hello()
    t = get_template('hello.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'name' : nome}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

I am stuck in : `ERROR testApp.hello: "title": "choices" should be a sequence of two-tuples.`

Any help kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what happens. The format for a choices field must be a tuple of tuple, something like this:

```
CHOICES=(
    ('f','foo'),
    ('b','bar'),
)
```

So in order to get your example to work, `nome` have to be initialized in some way that comply with the type expected, something like this:

```
nome=((x,x) for x in db.query(q))
```

But be careful. You should avoid doing direct `sql` queries to the database, even more that kind of simple queries. There should be a better way of doing that, like encapsulating the database calling into a method or something like that.

Also I notice that in `hello_template` you try to assign the value of `nome` to the `'name'` field int the line `html = t.render(Context({'name' : nome}))` That won't work because `nome` is not defined in the method. If you want to access nome you can do it like this `hello.nome` because as you defined it, `nome` is a class variable in the `hello` class so you have to access it through the class.